# Cocos2d-js/html5 inside a Django app

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, cocos2d-html5

I'm trying to use Cocos2d-html in a Django app.

From a HTML file, I need to refer to cocos2d.js, and from cocos2d.js I need to refer to another Javascript files.

Cocos2d.js is located in the [static folder]/js/
The other .js files that I need to refer from cocos2d.js are located in [static folder]/js/Platform and [static folder]/js/Src.

This is how I'm referring to cocos2d.js from the HTML file:

```
<script src={% static "js/cocos2d.js" %} ></script>
```

This is how I'm referring to the files from cocos2d.js

engineDir:'./Platform/HTML5/cocos2d/',

```
appFiles:[
    './Src/resource.js',
    '/Src/MainLayer.js',
    './Src/GameOver.js',
    './Src/main.js'
```

But when I run the html file, the game doesn't show up. How can I refer properly to these files inside the Django environment?

I also tried to create a global var with StaticDir in js like this:

```
window.STATIC_URL = '{{STATIC_URL}}';
```

And then concatenate the values:

```
engineDir: STATIC_URL + 'js/Platform/HTML5/cocos2d/',
```

But, them I get this error in Chrome console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/herorush/%7B%7BSTATIC_URL%7D%7Djs/Platform/HTML5/cocos2d/platform/jsloader.js:2
```